# Nodejs crypto vs python hashlib

Tags: python, node.js, cryptography, sha512, node-crypto

I'm trying to make a python function and a nodejs function compute the same hash. However, it seems like the binary that is outputted is different between nodejs crypto and python hashlib.

The python I'm using is:

```
hash = hashlib.sha512()
hash.update(salt)
hash.update(password.encode('utf8'))
hash.digest()
```

The node/coffeescript is:

```
crypto.createHash('sha512').update(salt, 'binary').update(password, 'utf8').digest()
```

These lines should produce the same result, but for some reason they don't. Help?

Comment: Could you include the results you get from running those two examples with example inputs?

Comment: When I run the exact same things, I get the same results—except that coffeescript returns a Unicode string (apparently Latin-1 decoded?), while Python (at least 3.x) returns a `bytes` value. So, I get things like `'\u0006'` vs. `'\x06'` for the third character.

Comment: After testing, it's true for Python 2.x as well.

Answer (score 4):

They do seem to produce the same result, but because node's `digest()` returns a Unicode string, while Python's returns a `bytes` object, this may not be immediately obvious:

CoffeeScript 1.4.0 on Node 0.8.11:

```
coffee> salt='abc'
'abc'
coffee> password='def'
'def'
coffee> d = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(salt, 'binary').update(password, 'utf8').digest()
'ã.ñ#èí&ezK=\u0007­»v\u0018\u0006CWEVNAP §\u0003¾*}¶\u001e=9\f+¹~-L1\u001fÜiÖ±&\u0005õ© ç'
```

Python 3.3.0:

```
>>> salt, password=b'abc', 'def'
>>> hash = hashlib.sha512()
>>> hash.update(salt)
>>> hash.update(password.encode('utf8'))
>>> d = hash.digest()
>>> print(d)
b'\xe3.\xf1\x96#\xe8\xed\x9d&\x7fez\x81\x94K=\x07\xad\xbbv\x85\x18\x06\x8e\x88CWEVN\x8dAP\xa0\xa7\x03\xbe*}\x88\xb6\x1e=9\x0c+\xb9~-L1\x1f\xdci\xd6\xb1&\x7f\x05\xf5\x9a\xa9 \xe7'
```

Looks pretty different, right? But if you look closely, the printable characters are the same—that `CWEVN` run is pretty obvious. And you can see even more similarities if you decode it as Latin-1…

```
>>> print(d.decode('latin1'))
ã.ñ#èí&ezK=­»vCWEVNAP §¾*}¶=9
                                   +¹~-L1ÜiÖ±&õ© ç
```

It's pretty obvious this is the exact same string, it's just that Node is escaping the non-printable characters.

And Python 2.7.2:

```
>>> salt, password='abc', u'def'
>>> hash = hashlib.sha512()
>>> hash.update(salt)
>>> hash.update(password.encode('utf8'))
>>> d = hash.digest()
>>> print(d)
?.?#??&ez??K=??v???CWEVN?AP???*}??=9
                                 +?~-L1?iֱ&? ?
>>> print(d.decode('latin1'))
ã.ñ#èí&ezK=­»vCWEVNAP §¾*}¶=9
                                   +¹~-L1ÜiÖ±&õ© ç
```

Again, same string.

Given that my terminal, C locale, etc. are all UTF-8 (this is OS X), I have no idea why CoffeeScript is decoding as Latin-1.