# Difference between NodeJS and Python Hashing

Tags: python, node.js, sha

I'm attempting to port some NodeJS code to Python 3, but am having trouble getting a SHA1 hash to behave identically.

This code in each language shows the problem:

**NodeJS**

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
crypto.createHash('sha1');
var h = crypto.createHash('sha1');
h.update(new Buffer('pXHepU2vIdYJuIAN', 'base64').toString('binary'));
console.log(h.digest('hex')); // ea70f5b1ec762290cefd37bc0f9a7421dcc93466
```

**Python 3**

```
import hashlib
import base64
h = hashlib.sha1()
h.update(base64.b64decode(b'pXHepU2vIdYJuIAN'))
print(h.hexdigest()) # 74161d2d37d9fff312dd396d5f779133c4bfd88d
```

I think I'm passing the Python input in the wrong format as if I remove the `.toString('binary')` from the NodeJS code it matches.

Could anyone explain to me what the Python code should be, and why they behave differently?

Comment: Compare the data before hashing it, look for any white space or line break character as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python code like this:

```python
import hashlib
import base64

h = hashlib.sha1()
h.update(base64.b64decode(b'pXHepU2vIdYJuIAN').decode('latin1').encode())
print(h.hexdigest()) #result is ea70f5b1ec762290cefd37bc0f9a7421dcc93466
```

I have referred to this question [Nodejs crypto vs python hashlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465048/nodejs-crypto-vs-python-hashlib)

Hope it helps you.